# Where did Queenie's spirit go?

Tags: american-horror-story

In *American Horror Story* season 5, I thought that the spirit of anyone who died in the Cortez stayed trapped there. So how come the guests at the beginning stayed trapped but then Queenie doesn't seem to appear anywhere after she died in the hotel?

She was one of the best characters from season 3 so it's kind of disappointing.